# Complex string matching in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a game: http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/xVMXQa

The game consists of the player guessing a word and they only have five attempts to guess it correctly. If one of the letters in the player's word is in its appropriate place, then it should become green. And if a letter is in the word, but not in the right place where it should be, it should paint red to give the player a hint that the letter is present, but should be placed somewhere else in the word. I used this part of the code to implement that feature:

```
if (userWord[i].toUpperCase() == word[i]){
    document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input].children[i].style.background = "green";
}
else if (word.indexOf(userWord[i].toUpperCase()) > -1){
    document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input].children[i].style.background = "red";
}
```

The issue is that when the player inputs a word that contains two or more same letters and the correct word contains less of that letter, only the letter that's in the exact place should be green and the other letters should not be red, because that would imply that the letter is there multiple times. For example:

- if the word is "ABBBB" and the player enters "AAAAC", only the first "A" of "AAAAC" should remain green and the other "A"'s should remain yellow and not become red.
- if the word is "ABABB" and the player inputs "ACBAA", the first "A" should remain green and only the second "A" should be red, not both of the last "A"'s to specify that there are only two "A"'s in the word. Also, the "B" should be red of course.
- if the word is "ABABA" and the player types in "AAAAA", then, only the first, the third and the last "A" should be green, but the other "A"'s should remain yellow and not become red.

So, those were some examples. I think you get the idea by now. I really couldn't figure out how to implement this feature correctly.

Comment: @wild-widow I think the community accidentally removed your suggested edits after I made a really tiny one... sorry about that, I'll attempt to make them now...

Comment: @Abdulah I have removed some text from your question that I didn't think was relevant, sorry if I was a little too restrictive, you may revert it as you see fit. On your question on asking different questions on your different issues, I think it's the best approach; asking all of your issues in the same question would make it very confusing and it would potentially end up being closed for that reason...

Comment: what is the condition for yellow?

Comment: @webeno no worries, thanks for answering that part of my question

Comment: @AnthonyChung Yellow is any letter that's not contained in the actual word

Comment: @АбдулахХамзиќ Did my solution work for you?  The answer you accepted is not javascript, html, or css?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place the guessed word and the desired word in a hash table (object) where frequency of letters are counted

Example2:

```
    actualWord = { a: 2, b: 3}
    guessedWord = { a: 3, b: 1, c: 1}
```

2. After each guess, iterate through both strings simultaneously
3. If the letter you are on matches, you highlight it green because it is both the right letter and in the right place.
4. Decrement both values in the hash table (they match and are no longer considered)

   ```
   actualWord = { a: 1, b: 3}
   guessedWord = { a: 2, b: 1, c: 1}
   ```
5. If they do not match, check the hash table. If the guessed letter is in the actualWord's hash table, it exists, but it is in the wrong place. Highlight it red. Decrement both by one

   ```
   actualWord = { a: 0, b: 3}
   guessedWord = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
   ```
6. If the lookup works, but the actual word's hash is 0, you know that the user input too many of the same letter, so you'd color it yellow (I think)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you.

First check if the letter are at the right place.

Then process the other letter.

every found letter increase the a counter for the specific letter.
So every time you can check if you have already found all of this letter.

```js
var target= "aabccd".toLowerCase();
var guess = prompt("guess the word(6 Letters)","").toLowerCase();

function countLetter(letter, string)
{
   var count = 0, n = 0, i = 0;
  
   while((i = string.indexOf(letter, n)) != -1)
   {
      n += i + 1;
      count++;
   }
  return count;
}

var guessLetterCount = {};
var style = [];
for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
  style.push("yellow");

// get letter who match
for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
{
  if(target[i] == guess[i])
  {
     style[i] = "green";
     if(guessLetterCount[target[i]])
          guessLetterCount[target[i]]++;
     else
          guessLetterCount[target[i]] = 1;
  }
}

// get letter at the wrong place
for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
{
  // only process letter who aren't at the right place
  if(style[i] == 'yellow')
  {
    // check if letter match and compare the letter count
    if(target.indexOf(guess[i]) != -1 && (guessLetterCount[guess[i]] == null ||   countLetter(guess[i], target) > guessLetterCount[guess[i]]))
    {
      // set read background
      style[i] = "red";
      if(guessLetterCount[guess[i]])
        guessLetterCount[guess[i]]++;
      else
        guessLetterCount[guess[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
}

// write result
for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
{
   document.write('<span style="font-size:20px; background:' + style[i] + '">'+guess[i]+'</span>');
  
}
```

Comment: I'll try this if my current code doesn't work out. Thanks!

Comment: I think we just did somebody's homework for them, Simon.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's your working answer.](https://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/jqRbam)  Note the test word is a variable titled 'word' and in this example is var word = 'AABBCC';

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>js</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .green{
          color:green;
        }
        .red{
          color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input"></input>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script> 
        var doc = document;
        var word = 'AABBCC';
        var input = doc.getElementById('input');
        var result = doc.getElementById('result');
        var inputArray = [];
        var colorArray = [];

        input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
            //clear result div and capture the string in the textbox
            var inputValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
            result.innerHTML = '';

            //wrap each character of the string in a <span>
            for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
                var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
                var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue.charAt(i));
                newSpan.appendChild(t);
                result.appendChild(newSpan);

                //capture each letter in an array
                inputArray[i] = inputValue.charAt(i);
            }

            //get position of last character
            var position = inputValue.length - 1;
            var thisChar = inputValue.charAt(position);
            var wordChar = word.charAt(position);            
            console.log('this char is ' + thisChar + ' and index is ' + position + ' and inputArray is ' + inputArray);

            var green = (thisChar === wordChar);
            var red = remains(thisChar,position);          

            if(green){
                colorArray[position] = 'green';
            } else if (red){
                colorArray[position] = 'red';
            } else {
                colorArray[position] = '';
            }
            color();
        });    

        function color(i, color){
            var children = result.childNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                children[i].className = colorArray[i];
            }
        }

        function remains(char,n){
            var found = false;
            //get the remaining substring of word to compare to
            var subString = word.substring(n);
            //if character is found return true
            for (var i = 0; i < subString.length; i++) {
                if(char === subString.charAt(i)){
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            return found;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```